# Can't get a route params in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a route like this

```
<a [routerLink]=" ['../projects', project.id] ">
```

And when i try get a route parameter from this url i don't get anything.

My import:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

My constructor:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

My on init:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params); //there i get only empty Object with `__proto__`
    });
  }
}
```

Who can help me with this?

Comment: Please provide more information. Ideally a Plunker that allows to reproduce. Reading params usually just works therefore the problem is probably somewhere else (route configuration, used components, ...)

Comment: Sory this is my error. I choose a bad way. Now i implement the service that save a project.id, And then use it in header.

Comment: That doesn't help. If you provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce it might be easier.

Comment: try this: `console.log(params.id);`

Answer (score 1):

Use snapshot to get the route parameter.

```
 let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
//do something here
```

Comment: this works but how do we subscribe? `this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => this.params = params);`